# How to reverse a std::list at a given position?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, reverse, stdlist

I am trying to figure out how to reverse for example,`grades{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}` starting at the third element.

I know for lists we cannot do `(grades.begin() + 2)` to obtain the position, but I'm not sure how to go about it.
This is what I have so far, where I'm just reversing the entire list:

```
reverse(firstList.begin(), firstList.end());
```

I want it to be reverse so that the list becomes: `grades{1, 2, 6, 5, 4, 3}`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I know for lists we cannot do `(grades.begin() + 2)` to obtain the position, but [...]

You are right about this. Providing the flexibility of `list.begin() + pos` means, it is cheap to do that. The `std::list` iterators(i.e. *[BidirectionalIterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/BidirectionalIterator)*) can not be randomly-accessed efficiently (i.e. it is expensive).  Therefore, as per the conventional, it must be verbose.

You need to be explicit to iterate via its element. That means, you can make use of [`std::next`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next) from `<iterator>` header to provide the starting point for [`std::reverse`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse).

```
#include <iterator> // std::next
#include <algorithm> // std::reverse

std::list<int> grades{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
std::reverse(std::next(grades.begin(), 2), grades.end());
//           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

[Live Demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/z13xcTEbx)